# numpy masked arrays or boolean indexing?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to perform dot(A,A.T) where certain indices are omitted:

```
In [6]: A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
In [6]: import numpy.ma as ma

In [7]: Ama = ma(A)
In [9]: Ama[0,0] = ma.masked
In [11]: ma.dot(Ama,Ama.T)
Out[11]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[13 28 43]
 [28 77 122]
 [43 122 194]],
         mask =
 [[False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]],
   fill_value = 999999)
```

What is the fastest way to do this? Note that I would like to keep the original dimension, i.e if A is square the dot product will have the same dimension.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that is fast to write, or a solution that is highly performant?

Comment: Solution that is highly performant. Also edited the code for more clarity. THAnks!

Comment: @methane You can time your solutions using `%timeit`.